# Jquery access img inside label

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, selector

I have these two checkboxes and I'm trying to access the img tag if the checkbox is selected to add a specific class. I don't know how to access the img tag.

```
<div class="row ">   
  <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1 col-centered piege">
    <input type="checkbox" id="piega1" class="piege servizioSection2 " name="imgSection2"value="Piega By Wella Professionals">
    <label  class="piega labelStylingImg " for="piega1">
      <img src="img/piega1.png" for="piega1" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega ">
    </label>
    <h1 class="immagineTitoloPiega">PIEGA BY WELLA PROFESSIONALS</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-5  col-centered piege">
    <input type="checkbox" id="piega2" name="imgSection2" class="piege servizioSection2" value="Piega By System Professionals">
    <label for="piega2" class="piega labelStylingImg">
      <img src="img/piega2.png" for="piega2" alt="" class="img-responsive immaginePiega">
    </label>
    <h1 class="immagineTitoloPiega">PIEGA BY SYSTEM PROFESSIONALS</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

My function should be: If the checkbox is selected add the borderRed class to the img.

I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(':checkbox').on('change', function (){
    if ($(this).hasClass('servizioSection2')) {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')){
        console.log('selected');
        var imgSelected = $(this).find('.immaginePiega');
      } else if ($(this).prop('checked', false)) {
        console.log('non selezionata');
      };         
    };
  })
});
```

I'm able to `console.log` selezionato but not to access the img tag and add the bordered class to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "add to it the borderred class"

Answer (score 1):

if :cheked add this

```
$(this).next().addClass('active');
```

and in else add this line

```
$(this).next().removeClass('active');
```

and add your custom css using this class .labelStylingImg.active img
For Example

```
.labelStylingImg.active img{ border: 2px solid red; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `next()` then `find()` Like this,

```
var imgSelected = $(this).next().find('.immaginePiega');
```

So you can now do this

```
imgSelected.addClass('bordered');
```

or

```
imgSelected.removeClass('bordered');
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/1kh329ck/)

Answer (score 0):

on change, get the label by `attr`,  the attribute "for" the checkbox id. 
The img is simply the descendant of it (and it also shares the same attr), which looks like simple traversing.

For example, simplifying a bit:

`$('#piega1').click(function(){ $('img[for=piega1]').addClass('borderRed');  });`

or more specifically to your case:

```
     $(':checkbox').change(function(e){
     var element = $('img[for='+$(e.target).attr('id')+']');
     if(element.hasClass('boderRed'))
         element.removeClass('borderRed');
     else
         element.addClass('borderRed');  });
```

Comment: please i'm having problem can you show me how to get label by attr on change?

Comment: I've added a simple example to the response, you can change the event `.change()`, or whatever you need.

Comment: Reworked it from a proper keyboard with a better fitted code to the example. It's harder to type code from the cell phone :).